# javascript - onload functions and setTimeout aren't work(renewal)

Tags: javascript, html

test2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style>
form {
    width: 330px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: pink;
    Padding: 20px;
}

input {
    text-align: right;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var pw;
    function create_form(_name, _action, _method, _target) {

        var instance = document.createElement("form");
        instance.name = _name;
        instance.action = _action;
        instance.method = _method;
        instance.target = _target;

        return instance;
    }

    function create_input_to_form(_form, _type, _name, _value) {
        var form_instance = _form;
        var input_instance = document.createElement("input");

        input_instance.type = _type;
        input_instance.name = _name;
        input_instance.value = _value;

        form_instance.insertBefore(input_instance, null);

        return form_instance;
    }

    function insert_form_to_html(_form) {
        document.body.insertBefore(_form, null);
    }

    function init() {

        var instance = create_form(
                "nuForm",
                "Test3.html",
                "post", "postWindow");
        insert_form_to_html(instance);
        pw = window.open("", "postWindow", "width=300, height=400");
        instance.submit();

        if (pw == null) {
            alert("error;");
        }
        else {
            pw.document.onload = function() {
                alert("wow");
            }
            document.write("1");
            pw.onload = function() {
                alert("wow2");
            }
            document.write("2");
            setTimeout(function(){
                alert("wow3");
                alert(pw.document.title);
            }, 3000);
            document.write("3");
        }

    }
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="init();">

</body>
</html>
```

test3.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>popup bodys
</body>
</html>
```

alert("wow");, alert("wow2");, alert(pw.document.title); doesn't working.
files are in same folder, and no errors and warnings appear when create a popup window.

i cannot understand why pw isn't local variables however use pw variable only in Init() function, and break down in timeout.

i test it in google chrome

---

there is a fixed test2.html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style>
form {
    width: 330px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: pink;
    Padding: 20px;
}

input {
    text-align: right;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">





    var pw;
    function create_form(_name, _action, _method, _target) {

        var instance = document.createElement("form");
        instance.name = _name;
        instance.action = _action;
        instance.method = _method;
        instance.target = _target;

        return instance;
    }

    function create_input_to_form(_form, _type, _name, _value) {
        var form_instance = _form;
        var input_instance = document.createElement("input");

        input_instance.type = _type;
        input_instance.name = _name;
        input_instance.value = _value;

        form_instance.insertBefore(input_instance, null);

        return form_instance;
    }

    function insert_form_to_html(_form) {
        document.body.insertBefore(_form, null);
    }

    function init() {
        var instance = create_form("nuForm", "Test3.html", "post", "postWindow");
        insert_form_to_html(instance);
        pw = window.open("", "postWindow", "width=300, height=400");
        instance.submit();

        if (pw == null) {
            alert("error;");
        } else {


            pw.onload = function() {
                alert("wow2");
                console.log("4");
            }
            console.log("2");
            console.log(pw);
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (pw==null) {
                    alert("pw is null");
                }
                else {
                    //console.log(document.domain);
                    console.log(pw);
                    //alert(pw.title);
                }

            }, 3000);
            console.log("3");
        }

    }
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="init();">

</body>
</html>
```

first problem is "alert("wow2");" and "console.log("4");" code doesn't execute when popup window complete its loading.

second problem is "console.log(pw);" into setTimeout() output null value, but another "console.log(pw)" output right popup window. why pw variable disappear although pw isn't local variable?

there is google chrome console when execute this file

```
2 Test2.html:69
'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead. VM56:423
Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}
 Test2.html:70
3 Test2.html:82
Window {}
```

Comment: Define "not working."  What do you expect to happen?  What is actually happening?  When you step through the code in a debugger, where does it differ from what you expect?  Are there any errors on the JavaScript console?

Comment: When you use `document.write("1");` you're loosing(ovewritting, indeed) your document content. Use `console.log()` instead in order to debug values.

Answer (score 2):

When your script comes to this part...

```
        pw.document.onload = function() {
            alert("wow");
        }
        document.write("1");
        pw.onload = function() {
            alert("wow2");
        }
        document.write("2");
        setTimeout(function(){
            alert("wow3");
            alert(pw.document.title);
        }, 3000);
        document.write("3");
```

... the events can even being set but you loose your document content using `document.write()`. So everything is lost. Because of this you can see `alert("error;");` but no other `alert()` of your code. You should use `console.log()` in order to debug such values. Just change:

```
document.write("1");
```

to...

```
console.log("1");
```

or if you really want to print the value to the document...

```
document.body.innerHTML = "1";
```

and others occurences.

Answer (score 1):

you can make init method changes like below:

```
    if (pw == null) {
        alert("error;");
    }
    else {

        pw.onload = function() {
            alert("wow2");
        }
        console.log("2");
        setTimeout(function(){
            alert("wow3");
            alert(pw.title);
        }, 3000);
        console.log("3");
    }
```

replace pw.document.onload to pw.onload. now it is working

you can find in this fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/QU7nP/